# How to get clone values with respect to Bean property values using json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a cone table having some input, check box and radio button values. so now i need to  save this values through ajax call .

Example:

```
var studentInfo = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    dob: $("#dob").val(),
    gender: : $('input[name=gender]:radio:checked').val(),
    collage: $("#collage").val(),
};
var studentJsonRequest = JSON.stringify(studentInfo);
```

The above is example is for only one table data so i get easily, if  am having clone table so how can i get that data like above example format i.e; json string format.

Comment: [Something like this..?](http://jsfiddle.net/dKSyL/)

Comment: Thanks,Bhavik.it was awesome answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function studentInfo() {
var studentInfoUrl = ".../studentInfourl"; 
var multiTags=$('.copy');
var name= multiTags.find("select.form-control#name").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
var dob= multiTags.find("input.form-control#dob").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
var gender= multiTags.find("#gender:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
var collage= multiTags.find(".input.form-control#collage").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(',');
var cloneName= '';
var cloneDob= '';
var cloneGender= '';
var cloneCollage= '';
var arr=[];
if($('.copy').length<=2){
      cloneName= name.split(',');
        cloneDob= dob.split(',');
        cloneGender= gender.split(',');
         cloneCollage= collage.split(',');
}
    for(var i=0;i<$('.copy').length ;i++){
        var studentInfo = {
                studentId  :   $("#studentId").val(),
                name       :   cloneName[i],
                dob        :   cloneDob[i],
                gender     :   cloneGender[i],
                collage    :   cloneCollage[i],
        };
        arr.push(studentInfo);
    }
    var astudentJsonRequest = JSON.stringify(arr);
    alert(arr);
    $.ajax({
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        data : astudentJsonRequest ,
        cache : false,
        type : "POST",
        url : studentInfoUrl ,
        success : function(data){}
```

});
}

Here i can get the individual input type values form clone table and then using the split method to split these values and after i find the length of clone table and assign these values to corresponding bean values.